# Help With Quant Modelling Software

Tags: modeling, risk-models, software, models

Im a software developer (freelance) working in investment banking, and I'm looking to improve my CV by gaining a better understanding of the financial quant role and the software used by quants to create and test models.
Ideally I'd like to write a high-performance desktop application in order to understand this area better.
My initial thoughts were to create an application that would be capable of consuming a variety of data feeds. The app would also include an F# code entry panel to allow the user to describe their model in a functional language. Then when the model is 'run' the output data stream is visualised as a real-time graphic.

My background is writing low-latency apps for front office, so I should be able to create something useful

Can anyone offer me advice about my project ? Is it a good idea or have I missed the point somehow ? would anyone like to help me (for a free copy of the resultant application) ? I would do it in my spare time (as Im current in a contract).

Im just trying to get into this space, and writing software is the best way for me to understand niche areas of this business.

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Hi Dean, welcome to quant.SE.  Do you have any specific questions beyond asking for advice and "is this a good idea?"  As I'm sure you know from your experience posting on SO, these forums tend to work best when there is a specific question at hand.

Comment: Im not sure how to phrase my need as a specific question. Ill give it some thought and update my question asap - thanks

Comment: What the heck is Quant Modeling Software?  Software for derivatives pricing?  Risk management?  Alpha research?  HF trading?  Interest-rate modeling?  Mortgage prepayment modeling?  Default modeling?  There's a ton of stuff out there so you obviously need to narrow it down.

Comment: Dean, you can start from this forum to gain an understanding of the tools and skills used in the industry: http://low-latency.com/ (I have no affiliation with the website).

Comment: thanks for all the comments guys, its been a great help :)

Comment: I'm afraid this will never be answered. @kfmfe04 makes a good point and choosing one of those could be the next step.